# I am not able to update a document in Firebase using Reactjs , Firebase return the the Document was updated successfully but it wasn't

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
try {
    const docRef = doc(db, `/taux/${uid}`);  
    await updateDoc(docRef, resultToupdate )
    updateDoc(docRef, resultToupdate , )
      .then(docRef => {
          console.log("Entire Document has been updated successfully", docRef);
          alert("Entire Document has been updated successfully");
      })
      .catch(error => {
          console.log("first::",error);
          alert(error);
      })
} catch (error) {
   console.log("second::",error);
    alert(error);
}
```

I am trying to update the content  "/taux/FvoDoByDE5VMK1MygHTEjupwS3E2" but it did not update .

Comment: What does `resultToupdate` look like? What logging output do you get on the console? And what does your document look like after the update completes (a screenshot of the Firebase console is probably best for this)? Please update your question to include the answer to all 3 questions.

Comment: first, why are you updating the document twice?  In the await and then again in the second call to updateDoc with a promise?

Comment: @majestiq he is probably trying to debug his code but thats not important. aouti alaeddine, can you show us the output of the code?